# Xcode 4 UIPage Control: How to change the height of the Page Control?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, height, uipagecontrol

I wanted to make the UIPageControl area (dots) shorter. I tried to change its height smaller in the Size Inspector but its height value is greyed out and it cant be changed. It's value by default is 36. Is there any way of decreasing this value programmatically? 
I know that you can make the page controllers background see through, but I don't want that. I wanted to make the background slightly transparent, I did that, but I want the Height of the background to be smaller.
If someone can help me out then that would be awesome.
THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

This is how you change the height of a UIPageControl.  In the PageViewController.m in the viewDidLoad method, put the following code:

```
self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 100);
```

This updates the frame property of the view of your UIPageControl.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CGRect frame = pageControl.frame;
frame.size.height = 10.0; // or whatever you want
pageControl.frame = frame;
```

This, of course, goes in your code, presumably in the controller that has access to your pageControl IBOutlet.

Comment: This does not seem to change the size of the dots for me.